# Why is my float automatically rounding and how do i get it to stop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Why is my float automatically rounding and how do i get it to stop

```
  float pageCount = 10/6;
```

should be 1.666
but it is giving  1.0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your calculation is being done in integer type since both the operands are of `int` type

cast or mark atleast one of the operand as float.

```
float pageCount = 10/6f; //6f specifying 6 as float
```

or

```
float pageCount = ((float) 10)/6;
```

In your current form, both operands are of integer type and their division results in integer value that is why you get `1` not `1.666`

Answer (score -1):

Simple to the following   `10.0/6`

Comment: This would result in an error `Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to 'float'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: Using 0.0 results in a double. You really need to use f to declare a float.